# jQuery AddClass method not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass

I am trying to add a new class to a "submit" input after checking that other form elements are filled up. I´m using .keyup() to trigger the function. This function changes the property "disabled" to "false", but after that it does not add the class " animate pulse ". Thanks!

```
<script> //checks that all fields are completed before enabling submit button
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
   $('input[type="text"],input[type="email"],input[type="password"]').keyup(function() {

      if($('#log_password').val() != '' && $('#log_email').val() != '') {
         $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false).addClass("animated pulse");
      }
      else{

        $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled',true);

      }
   });
  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Add seperately the addclass()

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);


  $('input[type="text"],input[type="email"],input[type="password"]').keyup(function() {

  if($('#log_password').val() != '' && $('#log_email').val() != '') 
  {
        $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
      //add in next line
     $('input[type="submit"]').addClass('animated pulse');
  }
  else{

    $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled',true);

  }
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is how are you using the `prop()` function since this function does not return anything, and the `addClass()` function needs to be called from a `jQuery` object.

As you can see on the [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) defintion it says:

> Returns: Anything

This practice is called **Chaining** and in order to do Chaining functions those functions should return a jQuery Object.

[More info](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/working-with-selections/#chaining)

You can rewrite your line of code by something like this:

```
$('input[type="submit"]')
  .addClass('animated pulse')
  .prop('disabled',  false);
```

Comment: Hey @ManoloHernándezKuri I just created a fiddle where you can see that this is working: https://jsfiddle.net/mitogh/8zqu4t7o/ if you inspect the class of the button now it has the new two classes it might a logic issue.